# Book about a soldier, who is a "?"th generation clone, who must recover the memories of his previous incarnation(s)

Tags: story-identification, books, clones

I remember reading a review of this book around 2000, though I do not know when it was actually written. I believe that the soldier was killed during an investigation of some sort. His clone is sent as a replacement to find out what transpired.

Comment: Are you sure it was a soldier? It reminds me of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_World_of_Null-A, which is an old small series of books.

Comment: This sounds pretty cool. I'm not 100% sure it was a soldier but pretty sure... and I don't think the book was quite so old.  I think part of the mystery was recovering old memories or finding out how his clones died.

Answer (score 4):

It could be Duncan Idaho in the Dune series (*Dune Messiah* and/or *God Emperor of Dune*). Frankly I can't recall the specifics, but I seem to recall that in at least one of them, the new Idaho clones had to undergo a certain trauma or imprinting in order to regain their past-life memories.

This played a role in several of the books including *Heretics of Dune* and *Chapterhouse: Dune*. IIRC, there was also a ghola of a commander Teg.

The clones were called "gholas."

Answer (score 3):

It reminds me of #2 in Mike Resnick's **The Widowmaker** series - Widowmaker Reborn:

[http://www.amazon.com/dp/0553571613](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0553571613)

also Walter Jon Williams' "Voice of the Whirlwind" might fit even better

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_of_the_Whirlwind

Comment: This might be it but I'm still not certain. Regardless, it sounds interesting and I'm going to check it out. Thanks!

Comment: I remembered a better fit so I edited the answer. I hope you enjoy the Widowmaker series :)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a lot like [Today We Choose Faces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Today_We_Choose_Faces) by Roger Zelazny. Protagonist is an assassin who uses cloning and memory transplants in an attempt to guide humanity. The final clone ends up having to pull up the memories of the the very first instance, Angelo di Negri.